# Fonts corrupted

Tags: unity, display, fonts

Fonts seems to be corrupted in Unity in my system after an update yesterday. It seems certain characters are refusing to display (please see attached screenshot), or gets displayed in same color as background. There is no such problem in gnome shell. However I prefer unity. Please help me resolve this. I have attached screenshots for better understanding

[image]

<sup>Click on the image to see a full-resolution version.</sup>

Comment: update : if i restart lightdm the fonts are ok. but i dont want to restart it everytime i log in. is there a permanent fix ?

Comment: Would you please indicate what sort of updates or other changes did you apply before the problem appeared? Were there any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/staging

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

That will reinstall unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didnt solve the problem :(

Comment: I had a similar problem and that worked for me.... Sorry I could help out though. :(